# google apps domain connection

Tags: dns, google-apps, cpanel

I have 2 domain names on google apps x.eu and y.com. x.eu with 50 users max and a new one (y.com) with 10 users. I was wandering if there is a way to connect these 2 domains on google apps and manage them with a single control panel. There is a setting under Domain settings -> Domain names -> "Add a domain or a domain alias  ( You can create user email addresses and aliases at any of your domains. )". What exactly will happen if I use this option ? so,

Q1: is there a way to connect these 2 domains on google apps and manage them with a single control panel.
Q2: What exactly will happen if I use "Add a domain or a domain alias" , and add x.eu to y.com ?
Also When I do this, I don`t want to loose the 50 users limit on my older domain ( x.eu )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my answer, I'm going to use the same terminology Google uses.  It's OK that you didn't ask the question with these terms, since you don't know what you don't know, and every software uses its own terminology, making it hard to find an answer when you don't know the right search terms to use.

What you're wondering is:

- How does multi-domain management work with Google Apps?

For that, you should check out this help center article:

http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=182452

In summary, **domain aliases** are typically used when users want to receive email from the same domain, e.g. jeff@mydomain.com and jeff@mydomain.org.  **Multiple domains** are typically used when you have a parent company and a subsidiary company, and they have separate email addresses, e.g. person_a@bridgestone.com and person_b@firestone.com (Firestone is a wholly-owned subsidiary of Bridgestone... though I don't think they're on Google Apps).  The help center article has a more complete discussion.

- Will I still be able to keep my grandfathered free 50 users on one domain, and free 10 users on another, if I merge them under one primary domain and another secondary domain?

No, sorry, that won't work.

Comment: thx, one more question if you are kind enough... if I merge the domains will have the 10 users from the newer domain or 20 ?